# How to convert from Avalon-MM 128-bit to 48-bit IF?

Tags: intel-fpga, soc, ddr3

Some Intel FPGA DDR memory controller only offers 48-bit Avalon-MM IF, when implementing the hard External Memory IF (EMIF) controller.

For connection from a 128-bit Avalon-MM IF, it is therefore required to make a conversion from lower frequency 128-bit Avalon-MM IF to a higher frequency 48-bit Avalon-MM IF.

Conversion in the other direction is usually also relevant.

Is there any standard way to convert from Avalon-MM 128-bit to 48-bit IF?

Comment: Got an anonymous "Close" vote in less than 25 minutes, with reason as "Opinion-based".  It would be very helpful with a comment about why it should be "Opinion-based" whether there is a standard way to do that conversion.  I would actually expect any existing standard way to exactly not be "Opinion-based", but rather the appropriate and right way to convert.